# ALTER COLUMN does not seem to convert datatype to LONG

Tags: sql, ms-access, alter-column

I'm trying to update my field data types. It seems to keep it as just an integer and I cannot update my database because the numbers are too large. I might just do the datatypes as Double if I can't get it to convert to long.

Here's the sql code I'm using for MS Access:
`ALTER TABLE Flows ALTER COLUMN Softener2 LONG`

Comment: The code should work.  Where are you running this code? Are you getting an error message?

Comment: Is this statement failing silently? Or is it returning a message of sort? What is the current datatype?

Comment: What was happening was that the database management software I am using is failing when I try to manually add the data. The SQL statements I've just ran in an ASP file I uploaded to my server. The statements don't fail at all.

Answer (score 1):

The ALTER TABLE statement you cited in your question does work. If I start with a table definition where [Softener2] is `Integer`...

[image: Flows1.png]

...and then close the table and run the following code...

```
Sub foo()
Dim cdb As DAO.Database
Set cdb = CurrentDb
cdb.Execute "ALTER TABLE Flows ALTER COLUMN Softener2 LONG", dbFailOnError
Set cdb = Nothing
End Sub
```

...the column is indeed changed to `Long Integer`

[image: Flows2.png]